# regex: Match when between text but not between digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help.
I need a regular expression (to be used in javascript) to replace "." with "#" in a text containing Unicode characters.
Replacement takes place only when "." appears between text but not between digits.

**Input:** "ΦΨ. ABC. DEF. 123.456"

**Desired output:** "ΦΨ# ABC# DEF# 123.456"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use capturing groups in the regex and use back-references to obtain the required result:

```js
var re = /(\D)\.(\D)/g; 
var str = 'ΦΨ. ABC. DEF. 123.456';
var subst = '$1#$2'; 
result = str.replace(re, subst);
alert(result);
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\D` - A non-digit character
- `\.` - A literal dot

The non-digit characters are captured into groups, and then inserted back with the help of `$1` and `$2` back-references.

Comment: @lor: I just wonder if you have cases when a dot is in the beginning or end of a sentence? Should they be replaced, too? Right now, they are not. If you want to turn them into `#`, use `var re = /(^|\D)\.(\D)|\.$/g; `.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str =  "ΦΨ. ABC. DEF. 123.456";

str.replace(/[^\d.]+\.[^\d]/g, function (m) {
    return m.replace('.', '#')
});
```